# Same size text looks bigger in mobile

Tags: css

Anybody knows why in mobile footer looks huge compare to other text here even though both are 13px?

http://goo.gl/7vIHZL

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: welcome to web design :]

Comment: :) guys there is no code needed to reproduce it. go to the link look at the bottom. you will see that it is huge. Why is it huge? I'm in this field since 2006 welcome to you Carrie. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixel measurement is relative to device screen size.  Try changing px to em, and if that doesn't work try % for the size of the font.  Here's a good converter: http://pxtoem.com